# Bootsfaces DropButton not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootsfaces

i want to use a DropButton from Bootsfaces in my JSF application but the Button dosn´t work. I can't see the menu Items and the Button dosen't develop.

```
<h:form>
<boot:dropButton value="Menü" tooltip="Einstellungsmenü">
            <boot:navLink value="Neuer Benutzer"
                            tooltip="Legt einen Neuen Benutzer an"
                            onclick="PF('neuerBenutzer').show()"
                            style="width:210px;" />
            <boot:navLink value="Benutzerverwaltung" icon="ui-icon-gear"
                            tooltip="Benutzerverwaltungsübersicht"
                            onclick="PF('verwaltung').show()"
                            immediate="true" />
</boot:dropButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't develop`? In my case your code looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/ulF4Chi.png). Do other BootsFaces components work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code snippet into my project, and it works like charm. So maybe there's something wrong with your project setup, or the BootsFaces version you're using is buggy. I don't believe that, but maybe you can check BootsFaces-0.9.2-SNAPSHOT oder BootsFaces-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, just in case. See https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/369 on how to get it.

For the sake of convenience, here's my complete working JSF page:

```
      <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>                                                                                                                                    
      <!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                                                                                            
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"                                                                                                                                 
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"                                                                                                                               
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"                                                                                                                               
            xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"                                                                                                                                   
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"                                                                                                                          
            xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" >                                                                                                                    
          <h:head>                                                                                                                                                               
              <title>StackOverflow issue</title>                                                                                                                                 
          </h:head>                                                                                                                                                              
          <h:body>                                                                                                                                                               
            <b:container>                                                                                                                                                        
                <h:form>                                                                                                                                                         
                    <b:dropButton value="Menü" tooltip="Einstellungsmenü">                                                                                                       
                                <b:navLink value="Neuer Benutzer"                                                                                                                
                                                tooltip="Legt einen neuen Benutzer an"                                                                                           
                                                onclick="PF('neuerBenutzer').show()"                                                                                             
                                                style="width:210px;" />                                                                                                          
                                <b:navLink value="Benutzerverwaltung" icon="ui-icon-gear"                                                                                        
                                                tooltip="Benutzerverwaltungsübersicht"                                                                                           
                                                onclick="PF('verwaltung').show()"                                                                                                
                                                immediate="true" />                                                                                                              
                    </b:dropButton>                                                                                                                                              
                </h:form>                                                                                                                                                        
            </b:container>                                                                                                                                                       
          </h:body>                                                                                                                                                              
      </html>
```

As for the pom.xml etc: I included the demo page in the [BootsFacesWeb showcase](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFacesWeb).

[image: BootsFaces b:dropButton demo]